# Digital Ocean: Dev + Production Droplets

Tags: install, deployment

I've been learning craft and want to setup a production & development environment. I've primary HTML CSS experience with limited backend or server related experience

One way I thought about doing this was setting up 2 separate droplets on Digital Ocean (w/ServerPilot) and copying digital ocean snapshots from the dev droplet to the production droplet.

- Is this a feasible approach?
- Does the license allow this if I don't map a domain to it and operate it as an IP address OR use an obscure term (staging etc.) in a odd **domain** (vs. sub-domain as mentioned in docs)?
- Is there a better (noob-friendly, learnable) way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does the license allow this if I don't map a domain to it and operate it as an IP address OR use an obscure term (staging etc.) in a odd domain (vs. sub-domain as mentioned in docs)?

Yes. As far as I'm aware, Pixel & Tonic consider a [development site](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/try-craft-client-pro) to be any [non public domain](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-enforcement#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain).

> Is this a feasible approach?
>   Is there a better (noob-friendly, learnable) way to do this?

Lumping these 2 together since they're directly related.  [This question and subsequent answers](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/host-a-craft-app/10496#10496)  might help you out as well as [Craft's own list of resources](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing#additional-resources).

It really depends on what you want to learn. When you spin up a droplet or other virtual machine, there's a lot of moving parts there. You'll be dealing with a lot of server management and not necessarily Craft development. It's easy to go really deep down the rabbit role and come out with a lot of (depending on what you seek out) useless knowledge. If you're just tinkering around, you probably want it as hands-off as possible.

Instead of paying for 2 droplet instances, you could spin up a virtual machine locally, like Virtualbox or something prebuilt like Laravel's Homestead. A droplet is also on the internet, thus a "public" server, so unless you want people hacking your instance, you'll want to secure it down. That just adds another layer of complexity.

Virtual machines are great solutions but they're also overkill usually. I find the easiest approach is to develop locally and use something like MAMP and then push it to staging and/or production servers. You don't need to worry much about the nitty gritty of permissions, firewalls, etc.

Comment: To add to the above, you can, to a certain extent, have the best of both worlds - use a service like Digital Ocean to make droplets but hand off the bulk of server and security management to ServerPilot.  In which case you could do droplet copies etc.  Not sure I would do deployments that way personally, but it's a really nice option that sits inbetween managed hosting and having to fully manage your own servers.